# Error (@websanova/vue-auth): drivers/http/axios.js: http plugin has not been set

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, authentication

I'm trying to setup vue-auth into my laravel-vue application.
But I'm getting console errors as

> Error (@websanova/vue-auth): drivers/http/axios.js: http plugin has not been set.

> Uncaught TypeError: this.plugins.http is undefined

and this is my **app.js** file content

```
import 'core-js/stable'

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import CoreuiVue from '@coreui/vue'
import { iconsSet as icons } from './assets/icons/icons.js'
import store from './store'
import VueAuth from '@websanova/vue-auth/dist/v2/vue-auth.esm.js';
import auth from './auth';


Vue.prototype.$apiAdress = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
Vue.config.performance = true
Vue.use(CoreuiVue)
Vue.use(VueAuth,auth)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,  
  icons,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {
    App
  },
})
```

and **auth.js** content

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import bearer from '@websanova/vue-auth/dist/drivers/auth/bearer.esm'
import axios from '@websanova/vue-auth/dist/drivers/http/axios.1.x.esm';
import router from '@websanova/vue-auth/dist/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x.esm';

// Auth base configuration some of this options
// can be override in method calls
const config = {
    plugins: {
        http: Vue.axios, // Axios
        router: Vue.router,
    },
    drivers: {
    auth: bearer,
    http: axios,
    router: router,
    tokenDefaultName: 'token',
    tokenStore: ['localStorage'],
    rolesVar: 'role',
   // registerData: {url: 'auth/register', method: 'POST', redirect: '/login'},
    loginData: {url: 'login', method: 'POST', redirect: '/dashboard', fetchUser: true},
    logoutData: {url: 'logout', method: 'POST', redirect: '/login', makeRequest: true},
    fetchData: {url: 'user', method: 'GET', enabled: true},
    refreshData: {url: 'refresh', method: 'GET', enabled: true, interval:30 },
    authRedirect: { path: '/' },
    parseUserData(response){
        let data = response.data;
        data.refresh = response.refresh_token;
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data));
        return data;
    }
},
    options: {
        rolesKey: 'type',
        notFoundRedirect: {name: 'user-account'},
    }

}

export default config
```

and I followed this tutorial https://websanova.com/docs/vue-auth/guides/startup to setup.
please help me to find what i am doing wrong.
**Laravel Framework 8.6.0 and vue": "^2.5.17"**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I could find a solution.And this can be solved using https://websanova.com/docs/vue-auth/guides/startup tutorial guides.

After installing the websanova/vue-auth plugin, There are some dependencies that must be set before the plugin is installed

**Router**

> The Vue.router must be set which then corresponds to the router driver installed with the plugin.

**HTTP**

> An http plugin must be set which then corresponds to the http driver installed with the plugin.

**as well as config.**

> Git: https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth/tree/master/demos/2.x/src

> I setup the application as it setup in git main.js file.

And it worked.